# How I can send json response from my spring controller?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm a newbie in the theme. How can I return JSON data from my controller, using something like that (using ResponseBody)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxtest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Set<String> ajaxTest() {
Set<String> records = new HashSet<String>();
records.add("Record #1");
records.add("Record #2");
return records; 
}
```

I tried ro use Jackson, but have http 406 error. 
What correct version of Jackson should I use with Spring version 4.0.3 and what is the algoritm of using?
**UPD**
Ajax call

```
<button id="btn">Click!</button>
<script>
$("#btn").click(
function sendAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajaxtest",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error:function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Why you don't use gson? With jackson i had so many problems.

Comment: Me prjofect doesn't see Gson class and can't resolve it. Can you show me an example? @ManuZi

Comment: take a look at the following: http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/

Comment: @ManuZI Maven can't compile project, because doesn't see gson jar. I tried to add it to my intellij libraries, but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you added it to the dependencies in your pom file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Converting to json request you must include following **3 jar** to your project build path.
**Jackson jar** is use for convrting **HTTP request to jason format.**

Also mention **headear=content-type=application/json**

**These are the jar files**

```
jackson-mapper-asl.jar
jackson-core-asl.jar
jackson-jaxrs.jar
```

Comment: Thanks, will try. But where I should mention the header?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxtest", method = RequestMethod.GET,header="contetnt-type=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Set<String> ajaxTest() {
Set<String> records = new HashSet<String>();
records.add("Record #1");
records.add("Record #2");
return records; 
}

Comment: i.e @RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxtest", method = RequestMethod.GET,header="contetnt-type=application/json")

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, you can include the following dependency in your pom.xml

Jackson Mapper Version 1 which is good enough to convert your object to JSON object:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Or you can also go for latest Jackson  version,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is an ancient version.